# Routing root request to this controller and action in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a URL request in the following format: `http://localhost/activate?activationCode=X`

I would like this request to be handled in the `Home` controller, by the `Activate` action.

I am not sure how to proceed. I have looked at `RouteConfig.cs` and see the way routes are defined here:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But how can I make `Home/Activate` handle URL's of the following format? `http://localhost/activate?activationCode=X`

...so as to add a special case where `activate` proceeding the host name goes to the `Home` controller, and `Activate` action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a specific route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Activate",
    url: "Activate/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Activate", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and place this one before the default route.

In addition if you want `http://localhost/activate/X` rather than `http://localhost/activate?activationCode=X`, then change it to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Activate",
    url: "Activate/{activationCode}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Activate", activationCode = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and make the method in `HomeController`

```
public ActionResult Activate(string activationCode)
```